# Safety: user-defined buffer pointers

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing, buffer-overflow

I have 3 buffers, each for separate data streams, in a library.

Currently, the input to the buffers is entangled with on-device data, but I want to generalize the input for off-device data to be pushed through the same algorithms without the preprocessing.

I see 2 options.

My safest option is to initialize the buffers in the library and control buffer overflow there.

```
#define BUFFSIZE 100
static float buff[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
static uint8_t bufferCount = 0;

bool pushSampleToBuffer(float sample)
{
    if(bufferCount < BUFFSIZE)
    {
        buff[bufferCount] = sample;
        bufferCount++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another option is to work with buffer pointers.
I see this as quite viable for the purpose of giving the user access to their own buffer, without duplicating it.

```
#define BUFFSIZE 100
static float* algBuffPtr = NULL;
static uint8_t algBuffSize = 0;

bool initAlg(float* buffPtr, uint8_t buffSize)
{
    if((buffSize < BUFFSIZE) && (algBuffPtr != NULL))
    {
       algBuffSize = buffSize;
       algBuffPtr = buffPtr;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a way to take the pointer approach and verify that the indicated addresses are valid more rigorously?

Comment: OT: Why don't you use booleans for boolean values? Why do you use 0 (`false` if C interprets it as boolean) for success? -- What kind of "_rigorously_" verification do you think of? Can your target system provide any information about valid addresses?

Comment: Do you need to modify the data in the buffer? is there any other thread that access to the buffer while you are processing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, any discussion about program safety is irrelevant if you allow dirty things like implementing buffers as global arrays. At an utter minimum declare them as `static` (which solves encapsulation but not thread-safety).

As for checking for buffer overflow, there's no obvious difference between arrays and pointers. Maybe except in case of an array you always have the base address at hand - this may or may not be the case when using pointers, if you allow the pointer to be modified (not `const`).

In embedded systems, it is common to implement double/tripple/etc buffering by declaring dedicated buffers but always accessing them through pointers. The reason for this is performance - you don't have to do `memcpy` or other CPU heavy operations when switching between for example "working buffer" and "verified buffer", you just swap the pointers (in a way safe from race conditions).

Ring buffer ADTs that handle size & overflow checks internally is another common solution.

Comment: This is a simplified example for example's sake. The implemented buffer is static.
What would you suggest if not an array?

To clarify why the pointer vs array question comes to mind:

The difference is where the buffer lives.
If the user defines the base address, it can be outside the compiled library which means that when this (very large) buffer grows, it can write into memory that it ought not to, correct?

Comment: @DanielWait I can't suggest anything since I don't know what you store there or intend to use it. Generally, it is considered good practice to allocate communication buffers in `.data` or `.bss`. Partially because they take a lot of space, partially because buffer overruns on the stack could be considered more catastrophic than buffer overruns in static memory. With that in mind, allowing caller-allocated buffers may or may not be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have only superficial knowledge of some of these concepts, so you're helping me pin things down.
Because the library is compiled to a DLL for various target types, my safest option is to define the arrays internal to the lib. The buffers will be guaranteed to live in the .bss section when the archive is linked.
Still, plenty of caution shall be taken to prevent overflow.

Comment: @DanielWait A DLL for embedded signal processing applications? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Library rather. It's compiled for various targets (x86, ARM, etc.). The main application is for embedded targets, but we use python wrappers for testing with .dll/.so. Obviously would be .a/.lib for embedded.

Comment: You don't need to create a .dll/.so for PCs, you can as well use .lib/.a there. This should simplify the build.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re making the decision of delegating your library’s resource creation to the user in order to give them more control, I don’t see why you would then want to unnecessarily burden it by trying to validate anything other than the rudimentary.

So long as you have a clear API and test what happens if you provide a dodgy buffer (so you can communicate the risk), and so long as what happens is not that the universe implodes, then I would suggest that it’s OK to just trust that your library will be used correctly.